uploading file larger than 2M to s3 using php
I am am trying to upload video file to s3 using aws php library:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject
I do succeed to upload files smaller than 2M . but when file is larger than 2M I got this warning :
fwrite(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory. in <b>/aws/GuzzleHttp/Psr7/Utils.php</b> on line <b>309</b>

the warning referring to this part of code in aws library:
public static function streamFor($resource = '', array $options = [])
    {
        if (is_scalar($resource)) {
            $stream = self::tryFopen('php://temp', 'r+');
            if ($resource !== '') {

/////////////here 

                fwrite($stream, $resource);
                fseek($stream, 0);
            }
            return new Stream($stream, $options);
        }

according to :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#:~:text=One%20difference%20between%20the%20two,as%20the%20sys_get_temp_dir()%20function.
I need to change the code in aws library to:
    $stream = self::tryFopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+');

and when I do it . I do succeed to upload files larger than 2M to s3.
my question , do I have to do this change in aws library . or I should use another function ?
thanks

You don't need to change the AWS SDK code.
From the docs you linked:

whereas php://temp will use a temporary file once the amount of data
stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB). The location of
this temporary file is determined in the same way as the
sys_get_temp_dir() function.

You error message is then given as:

Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory

In other words, your script has exceeded the in-memory limit of 2Mb and so PHP is now trying to automatically fall back to a system temporary file instead. However, the user that your PHP process runs as does not have write permission to the directory where PHP thinks it should store such files. This is defined by the sys_temp_dir setting in your php.ini file, which is usually:
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"

You can run echo sys_get_temp_dir(); to see what PHP thinks your temp dir is, perhaps it has been changed from the default. And then either adjust the system permissions on that directory (so that the PHP user can write there) or change your php.ini file to point to a different location.
